# How to check access to Cost & Usage Reports tab using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, billing, cost-management

I am trying to use AWS boto3 for my app.
After looking in boto3 documentation I couldn't find the Billing APIs.
The purpose of my app is to check if I have access to the Cost and Usage Reports.
If I don't have (like in the picture) I want the script to notify me:
[image]

How can I check it? The credentials I use are credentials I get after assuming role
I have tried the following:

```
costExplorer = boto3.client(
    'ce',
    aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken']
)

endTime = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
if endTime.month == 1:
    startTime = datetime(endTime.year - 1, endTime.month + 11, endTime.day)
else:
    startTime = datetime(endTime.year, endTime.month - 1, endTime.day)

timePeriod: Dict[str, str] = {
    'Start': startTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
    'End': endTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
}
# if it raise exception -> Means I don't have access to the Cost & Usage Reports tab
costExplorer.get_cost_and_usage(TimePeriod=timePeriod, Metrics=["UsageQuantity"])
```

This code works when I don't have access but it also raise exceptions when I **do have** access

Comment: What is the  exception and its error message?

Comment: @Marcin botocore.exceptions.ClientError (Acess Denied) when trying to perform GetCostAndUsage but it raises an exception although I have access to the Cost and Usage Reports tab via the console

Comment: The credentails for boto3 are are same as yours? Do you use `us-east-1` region?

Comment: @Marcin The credentials are not the same but I assume_role before it and get the credentials from the return value

Comment: Does the role have permissions to access `GetCostAndUsage`. Seems it does not.

Comment: @Marcin I agree, but what method should I use in order to check if I have access to the Cost & Usage reports? This exception is thrown also when I do have access with the role

Comment: Did you enable access to billing for IAM users? It might be the issue here. especially if you're seeing the billing from the root user